# Cannot override property getter with XCode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

I am having some problems with some old sample code when using it with Xcode 4.5.

In my code I have the following property defined

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
```

Then I have the following accessor method:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyPrototype" 
                                                   withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] 
                                          initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

The problem is that Xcode throws multiple errors as it cannot 'see' `_managedObjectModel`. If I change the name of the accessor from `managedObjectModel` to `managedObjectModel2`, everything works fine. I guess that the issue is related to `Xcode 4.5` automatic property synthesizing, but I don't know what I should do to avoid the issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Clang won't automatically synthesize an instance variable for you if it doesn't have any methods to generate. In this case, you've asked for a readonly property, so there's no setter, and you've providing the getter. You can just `@synthesize managedObjectModel=_managedObjectModel` or just declare the instance variable yourself.

Comment: @Huibert, if it's soved, you should mark the answer as correct

Comment: Thanks, Luis.I didn't realize that. This was my first question, certainly not the last. Great community.